# Summation of a quotient with a square root: $ \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{inx}}{\sqrt{k^{2}-(n+\alpha)^{2}}(n+\beta)} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions

Is anyone aware of an expression for the following series, presumably involving a special function?
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{inx}}{\sqrt{k^{2}-(n+\alpha)^{2}}(n+\beta)}
$$
Mathematica won't evaluate the sum and I can't find it in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik. It would be helpful even to have an expression for the case $x=0$ (i.e. $1$ on the numerator). Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What are $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $k$?

Comment: They are all real constants. I envisage them to be parameters in the special function.

Answer (score 1):

I tried [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula), but it clearly fails. I [learned](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4255028/how-to-evaluate-sum-limits-x-0-infty-texterfcx-1-16199904794712636353) a technique which uses a floor function like for this [**case**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F%28sqrt%28n%5E2%2B1%29%28n%2B1%2F2%29%29+from+0+to+3000%2Bintegral+-%282+%282+%2B+n+%2B+4+n%5E2%29%29%2F%28%281+%2B+2+n%29%5E2+%281+%2B+n%5E2%29%5E%283%2F2%29%29floor%28n%2B1%29+from+0+to+2000). You can find the sum over the negative reals from the positive reals sum. Note that the $\lfloor x+a\rfloor$ may take on different “a” values.

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{inx}}{\sqrt{k^{2}-(n+a)^{2}}(n+b)}=\int_0^\infty \lfloor x+a\rfloor \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{e^{inx}}{\sqrt{k^{2}-(n+a)^{2}}(n+b)}\right)dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\lfloor x+1\rfloor(a + n) e^{i n x}}{(b + n) (k^2 - (a + n)^2)^\frac32} + \frac{\lfloor x+1\rfloor i x e^{i n x}}{(b + n) \sqrt{k^2 - (a + n)^2)}} - \frac{\lfloor x+1\rfloor e^{i n x}}{(b + n)^2 \sqrt{k^2 - (a + n)^2)}}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor(a + n) e^{i n x}}{(b + n) (k^2 - (a + n)^2)^\frac32} + \frac{\lfloor x\rfloor i x e^{i n x}}{(b + n) \sqrt{k^2 - (a + n)^2)}} - \frac{\lfloor x\rfloor e^{i n x}}{(b + n)^2 \sqrt{k^2 - (a + n)^2)}}dx+ \frac{e^{i\infty x}}{\sqrt{k^{2}-(\infty+a)^{2}}(\infty+b)}-\frac{1}{b\sqrt{k^2-a^2}} $$

Also see [alternate forms of the Floor function](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/Floor/27/). This should work as the bolded link link demonstrates so. There are other options we have, but I may not find a function which “fits” the summation. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: This is an old answer, so it may be of slightly lower quality