# Is there a better solution for $\mathrm{\int (a^t)^{(a^t)}dt= C+t+\frac1{\,ln(a)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n Q(n+1,-nt\ln(a))}{n^{n+1}}\,dt}$?

Tags: integration, exponential-function, hypergeometric-function, tetration, power-towers

I know there exist functions like [this one](https://daydaynews.cc/en/constellation/sophomore-dream.html) for simplifying tetration based sums. There may be a way to simplify this type of sum at least using a lesser known and widely accepted functions. Here are some results as proof: [**graphical visualization of results**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wnpiszyx1s) and [calculation of special case](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1-sum%28-1%29%5En+%CE%B3%28n%2B1%2Cn%29%2F%28n%5E%28n%2B1%29+n%21%29++from+n%3D+1+to+20) and [integral version of special case](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%28e%5Et%29%5E%28e%5E+t%29+from+-1+to+0).

It was a nice idea to find the [sophomore’s dream](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream), but I thought that it would be more interesting if I could find a “generalized exponential sophomore’s dream”. This post uses the following functions: [regularized gamma functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedGammaFunction.html), the [exponential integral](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/ExpIntegralE/) function, and [tetration](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration). There was an annoying discontinuity at n=0 hence the constant term:

$$\mathrm{\int_0^b \, ^2\left(a^t\right) \, dt=\int_0^b a^{ta^t} \, dt = b + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln^n(a)}{n!}\int_0^b t^n a^{tn} \, dt = \boxed{\mathrm{b+\frac1{\ln(a)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nP\big(n+1,-n\,b\ln(a)\big)}{n^{n+1}}}}\implies \int_{-\frac1e}^0 e^{{te}^t} \, dt = 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nP(n+1,n)}{n^{n+1}}=0.77215…}$$

$$\mathrm{\implies A(a,t)\mathop=^\text{def}\int \,^2\left(a^t\right)dt=C+t+\frac1{ln(a)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n Q(n+1,-nt\,ln(a))}{n^{n+1}}=\quad C+t-t\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(t\,ln(a))^n E_{-n}(-nt\,ln(a))}{n!}}$$

This series reminds me of the [Marcum Q function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcum_Q-function) for non negative integers:
$$\mathrm{Q_m(a,b)=1-e^{-\frac{a^2}2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{a^2}{2}\right)^n\frac{P\left(m+n,\frac{b^2}2\right)}{n!}}$$

This representation is good, but is quite tedious to use as the formula requires summing an infinite amount of regularized gamma functions. I would like to find a way to get rid of the summation .I see the gamma function with powers which reminds me of the summation definition of a [hypergeometric function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function). I would even like to see the use of a [**generalized hypergeometric**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunctions.html) function like Meijer G or Kampé de Fériet functions seen in the link. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: Can you please make the definitions of the functions clear i.e. $P$,$Q$ and $E_n$?

Comment: @JamesArathoon It states “ This post uses the following functions: [regularized lower gamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedGammaFunction.html) which is quite rare, the [exponential integral](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/ExpIntegralE/) function, and [tetration](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration).” This already gives links to the functions, but I emphasized these appear in the post.

Comment: I think you should use a different word for your links to graphical web plotting program / plot comparisons you use than "proofs".

Comment: You style of typesetting is quite unusual, and I might take it to be a deliberate personal style choice but for the fact that some of the MathJax code looks like what comes from some of those software packages that write MathJax code for those who don't write it themselves.

Comment: @MichaelHardy It is just easier to use \mathrm{code} and no extra spaces between the  differential and equal signs. It is just how I adapted. The \mathrm{} makes it so you can just write \mathrm{$ln(x)$} and not \$\ln(x)$ Your comparison of my style to “some of those software packages” is a fun thought. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: My comparison to "some of those software packages" resulted in part from the fact that you wrote things like `\left(x\right)` rather than just `(x)`. Using `\left` and `\right` is needed to make `(`  and `)` grow to the size of the things they enclose, but has no effect when only `x` is enclosed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply not possible to write the integral in terms of a closed-form solution because $ \int (a^{t})^{(a^{t})} \textrm{d}t $ is non-elementary. All elementary functions can be expressed using a finite number of elementary functions and operations, like addition, subtraction, multiplication, fractions, exponentiation, logarithms, trig functions, inverse trig functions, hyperbolic trig functions, and inverse hyperbolic trig functions. Since the integral you're interested in has no elementary solutions, it cannot be written in closed form. So as unfortunate as it sounds, this is probably the best solution to it you're gonna get.

**Edit 1:** It appears as though I was a bit too hasty in my judgement; yes, this integral is indeed non-elementary, but it actually has a nice solution if you have an open mind!

Observe:

$$ \int (a^{t})^{(a^{t})} \textrm{d}t = \int (e^{t\ln(a)})^{(e^{t\ln(a)})} \textrm{d}t $$
$$ \int (e^{t\ln(a)})^{(e^{t\ln(a)})} \textrm{d}t = \int e^{t\ln(a)e^{t\ln(a)}} \textrm{d}t $$
$$ u = t\ln(a) \implies \textrm{d}t = \dfrac{\textrm{d}u}{\ln(a)} $$
$$ \int e^{t\ln(a)e^{t\ln(a)}} \textrm{d}t = \dfrac{1}{\ln(a)}\int e^{ue^{u}} \textrm{d}u $$

Alrighty then. I was pretty excited when I got to this point, because what nice function conveniently eliminates expressions of the form $xe^{x}$? Let us see:

$$ u = W(v) \implies \textrm{d}u = W'(v)\textrm{d}v $$
$$ \dfrac{1}{\ln(a)}\int e^{ue^{u}} \textrm{d}u = \dfrac{1}{\ln(a)}\int e^{W(v)e^{W(v)}} W'(v) \textrm{d}v $$
$$ \dfrac{1}{\ln(a)}\int e^{W(v)e^{W(v)}} W'(v) \textrm{d}v = \dfrac{1}{\ln(a)}\int e^{v} W'(v) \textrm{d}v $$

And for the finale...

$$ \int e^{v} W'(v) \textrm{d}v = W(v)e^{v} - \int W(v)e^{v} \textrm{d}v $$
$$ v = \ln(z) \implies \textrm{d}v = \dfrac{\textrm{d}z}{z} $$
$$ \int W(v)e^{v} \textrm{d}v = \int W(\ln(z))e^{\ln(z)} \dfrac{\textrm{d}z}{z} $$
$$ \int W(\ln(z))e^{\ln(z)} \dfrac{\textrm{d}z}{z} = \int W(\ln(z))z \dfrac{\textrm{d}z}{z} $$
$$ \int W(\ln(z))z \dfrac{\textrm{d}z}{z} = \int W(\ln(z)) \textrm{d}z $$

Unfortunately, this is where our journey ends. However, you could always define a special function, so that's exactly what I'm gonna do!

$$ \textrm{Wi}(x) := \int_{1}^{x} W(\ln(\xi)) \textrm{d}\xi $$

And now, we can finally clean things up:

$$ \int e^{v} W'(v) \textrm{d}v = W(v)e^{v} - \textrm{Wi}(z) $$
$$ W(v)e^{v} - \textrm{Wi}(z) = W(v)e^{v} - \textrm{Wi}(e^{v}) $$
$$ W(v)e^{v} - \textrm{Wi}(e^{v}) = ue^{ue^{u}} - \textrm{Wi}(e^{ue^{u}}) $$
$$ ue^{ue^{u}} - \textrm{Wi}(e^{ue^{u}}) = (t\ln(a))e^{(t\ln(a))e^{t\ln(a)}} - \textrm{Wi}(e^{(t\ln(a))e^{t\ln(a)}}) $$

And as always, never forget your constant multiples and +C!

$$ \dfrac{1}{\ln(a)}\left((t\ln(a))e^{(t\ln(a))e^{t\ln(a)}} - \textrm{Wi}(e^{(t\ln(a))e^{t\ln(a)}})\right) + C $$

**Edit 2:** This needs a bit more tidying up...

$$ ta^{ta^{t}} - \dfrac{1}{\ln(a)}\textrm{Wi}(a^{ta^{t}}) + C $$

**Edit 3:** I made a slight error when doing IBP; I added the integral part instead of subtracting it. Oops.

Comment: Unless you can prove otherwise, there exists a whole world out there of special functions with weird and wonderful series definitions. Please see this [**post of special functions**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3683374/summation-and-integral-representations-of-special-functions) in MSE. Try to find a function that has a related expression and can be molded into the series seen above in my question. Thanks for the effort!| I know it is non-elementary, so I would like to find a special function representation.

Comment: In that case, I'll keep checking.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. This is an infinite sum of gamma functions which can be used to solve similar problems. The functions should be academically recognized. Perhaps a Hypergeometric function?

Comment: No worries, that's what MSE is for!

Comment: Alright! I hope the answer is not too sloppy; it was all I could think of.

Comment: This should have been an invented known function. I guess you did find a better integral solution with. I will accept, but maybe you could please find an actual function? I still like the answer.

Comment: I'll try looking on Mathematica to see if there are already named functions similar to the product-log-integral function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128094/discussion-between-tyma-gaidash-and-arjun-vyavaharkar).

Comment: I found a summation form for $$\mathrm{Wi(x)=\sum_{n\ge1}n^{n-1}P(n+1,-ln(x)),|ln(x)|<\frac1e}$$Here is an [**interactive graph**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/i1reyvaezw). P(a,b) is the Regularized Lower [Incomplete Gamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedGammaFunction.html) and [the expansion](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ProductLog/06/01/01/0003/) used for W(x).

Comment: This converges for desmos, but not on Wolfram Alpha…

Comment: Fascinating... You could also potentially use the integral representation of $W(x)$, which goes as follows: $$ \dfrac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \ln\left(1+x\dfrac{\sin{t}}{t}e^{t\cot{t}}\right) dt $$

Comment: Of course, that form only works for the principal branch of $W(x)$, but hey, it's better than nothing ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Here is a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4214432/does-mathrm-int-wlnxdx-mathop-or-int-wxex-dx-have-a-closed-form) for a closed form of Wi(x). There probably is not a closed form, but it is worth a shot. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this is probably the best I can do. I think you'll have more luck expressing the solution in terms of more widely known functions than I will, but I think I'll look for other questions in the meanwhile. Thanks for the question! This was very insightful for me and helped open my mind to the possibility of potentially standardizing exotic functions.