# Solve $\sum_{n=1}^\inftyΓ(-n,-n)\mathop= \pi\left(\frac1e-1\right)i+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \text{Ei}(n)}{n!}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n･(-e)^n $

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, gamma-function, constants, tetration

Motivation:

It may be possible to find an integral representation using:

> [Integral form(s) of a general tetration/power tower integral solution: $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(pn+q)^{rn+s}Γ(An+B,Cn+D)}{Γ(an+b)}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4232284/integral-forms-of-a-general-tetration-power-tower-integral-solution-sum-lim)

After seeing

> [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4135449/area-under-x-x-over-its-real-domain-what-is-another-non-integral-form-of)

with the use of [*gamma functions*](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/), I found that $$\mathrm{\int_0^\frac1e x^{-x} dx=\mathop \sum_{n≥1}\frac{Q(n,n)}{n^n}=\mathop \sum_{n≥0}\frac{E_{−n}(n+1)}{n!}=.48689…}$$
[source 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28integral+x%5E-x+from+0+to+1%2Fe+%29-%28sum+Q%28n%2Cn%29%2Fn%5En+from+1+to+1000%29+)
[source 2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral_0%5E%281%2Fe%29+x%5E%28-x%29+dx+-+0.486899)

Here is a [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vmfmltlbxd) of the real side of the second to last series.

This result made me wonder  how to evaluate the following. The definition of the exponential integral function still works as Re(n)<0:$$\mathrm {S\mathop=^{def}\sum_{n\in \Bbb Z^-} Γ(n,n)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty Γ(-n,-n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{E_{n+1}(-n)}{(-n)^{n}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{-n}^\infty \frac{dt}{t^{n+1}e^t}= \int_1^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{nt}}{(-n)^nt^{n+1}}dt=\sum_{n=1}^\infty Q(n,n)Γ(n)=-0.5948551252563932027611440348… + 1.98586530379887152055255019996… i}$$

Here is an attempt at an integral representation. If only I could find a summation that I could evaluate because this “$n^n$” in the denominator makes it hard to find a closed form for the sum:
$$\mathrm{S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int \frac d{dx} Γ(-n,-n\,x)\big|_0^1dx=\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{nx}}{n^n x^{n+1}}dx\implies S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_a^b \frac d{dx} Γ(-n,-n\,f(x)) dx =\int_a^b \sum_{n=1}^\infty -\frac{e^{n\,f(x)}f’(x)}{(-n\,f(x))^nf(x)}dx}$$

S converges because of this [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gamma%28n%2Cn%29) and is almost an alternating series with the absolute value of the summand decreasing to 0. Here are the partial sums for the negative bounds of summation:

[image]

[image]

Finally, here is the graph of the summand Γ(n,n) plotted at the index bounds:

[image]

A possible hint is understanding how to derive the $\int_0^\frac1e x^{-x}dx $ integral sum. You can “reverse” substitute and “reverse” integrate as I showed above.

The following uses an [exponential integral function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/ExpIntegralE/). Here is a result showing that you can easily find an alternate expression for “S” using @Steven Clark’s great answer in:

> [Nice result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4201088/how-to-find-mathrm-sum-n-1-infty-e-nn-lim-k-to-infty-int-1-infty/4201115#4201115)

$$\mathrm{\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{xe^x-1}=\sum_{n\ge1} E_{n}(n)=.269292…}$$

Here is a third example to support that this “S” constant should have another expression. This example uses the [lower regularized incomplete gamma function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Regularized_Gamma_functions_and_Poisson_random_variables):

> [Related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4192244/finding-another-form-of-mathrm-int-atatdt)

$$\mathrm{\int_{-1}^0 e^{te^t}dt=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nP(n+1,n)}{n^{n+1}}=.772158…}$$

Here is a possible form using the [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula). It may theoretically converge, but Wolfram Alpha has trouble finding it numerically. There are many possibilities for substitution, so I will leave it here:

$$\mathrm{\sum_{n=0}^\infty Γ(-n-1,-n-1)=\frac{Ei(1)-e+i\pi}{2}+\int_0^\infty Γ(-x-1,-x-1)+i\frac{Γ(-ix-1,-ix-1)-Γ(ix-1,ix-1)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx}$$

Here is theoretically working [integral representation](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma2/07/02/). We can integrate by each term:

$$\sum_1^\infty Γ(-n,-n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{Γ(x-n)Γ(x)}{Γ(x+1)(-n)^x}dx=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{k-i\infty}^{k+i\infty}\frac{1}{ (-1)^{x}x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{Γ(x-n)}{n^x}dx,\text{max}(\text{Re}(n),0)<k$$

How can I find an alternate representation for “S”? You can find a better integral expression of “S”. If not, then please find a closed form, optional,  or a series representation which converges faster. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: What makes you so sure there is a representation of S other than as the infinite sum?

Comment: @Tyma_Gaidash I read it, but I don't see how the fact that $\sum \frac{Q(n,n)}{n^n}$ has a convenient compact integral form means that S needs to have one too

Comment: @Tyma_Gaidash I'm not saying it doesn't exist.  I have no clue if it exists.  My point is that your question makes the assumption that it exists; I want to know what is behind that assumption

Comment: @TymaGaidash $\Gamma(-n,z)$ has a logarithmic branch point at $z=0$. What do you mean by $\Gamma(-n,-n)$?

Comment: As I said there is a logarithmic singularity at $z=0$. There is no analytic continuation to $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb C$ minus the origin. The value of the integral you are proposing will depend on the path of integration. Computer algebra softwares are often bad with multivalued functions.

Comment: @Gary Yes, maybe you can find the correct path as I am not as well versed in complex analysis. We can try using the exponential integral form of “S” as seen in the question and bounty notice. Also, W|Alpha can give closed forms for Γ(-1,-1),Γ(-2,-2),etc. which may serve as a hint maybe?

Comment: WA defines $\Gamma ( - n, - n) = \Gamma ( - n,ne^{\pi i} )$.

Comment: @Gary Yes, -1=$e^{\pi i}$. I guess this means the principal branch. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty easy to find a closed form for the imaginary part of the sum. Here is some motivation for finding the rest of the answer by expanding and putting corresponding terms into an infinite sum:

$$\sum_{-\infty}^{-1} \Gamma(n,n)=\text{Ei(1)}+i\pi-\frac{\text{Ei(2)}+i\pi }2+ \frac{\text{Ei(3)}+i\pi }{6}-\frac{\text{Ei(4)}+i\pi }{24}+…-e+\frac{3e^2}8-\frac{7e^3}{81}+\frac{47 e^4}{3072}+… =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\pi i}{n!}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \text{Ei}(n)}{n!}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(-e)^n, a_n=\left\{1,\frac38,\frac7{81},\frac{47}{3072},\frac{427}{187500},\frac{13}{43740},\frac{36013}{1037664180},\frac{155011}{42278584320},…\right\}$$

Therefore we can use the series expansion for $e^x$ and simplify:
$$\sum_{-\infty}^{-1} \Gamma(n,n)= -0.5948551252563932027611440348 +\pi\left(\frac1e-1\right)i= \pi\left(\frac1e-1\right)i+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \text{Ei}(n)}{n!}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(-e)^n $$

I tried using the following identify with the [Generalized Exponential integral function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/ExpIntegralE/):

$$\text{Ei}(x)+i\pi=-\text E_1(-x),\text E_v(z)=\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-zt}}{t^v}dt,\text{Re}(z)>0$$

which did not work with the restriction.

We could probably do something similar to:

> [Prove $$\displaystyle\sum_{-\infty}^0\text H(x)=\frac12\sum_0^\infty\frac{\text H_\frac x2-\text H_\frac{x-1}2}{x!}=\frac{\text{Ei}(2)-\text{Ei}(1)}e$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4264299/prove-displaystyle-sum-infty0-text-hx-frac12-sum-0-infty-frac-text-h)

which implies the [Gompertz Constant G](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GompertzConstant.html) which is very close to the real part of the sum:

$$-\text G=e\text{Ei}(-1)=  -0.59634736232319407434107849936927 ≈\text{Re}\sum_{-\infty}^{-1} \Gamma(n,n)= -0.5948551252563932027611440348 $$

How can I find the rest as an integral or in closed form? Please correct me and give me feedback!