# On $\mathrm{\sum_{x\in\Bbb Z}sech(x)=3.142242…}$

Tags: trigonometry, summation, closed-form, hyperbolic-functions, q-series

Inspired by

> [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4195180/finding-the-complex-number-sum-n-1-infty-%CE%93-n-n),

I started to wonder about simpler series. I have seen similar questions to the following, but none had this special case explicitly. It is related to the [q-digamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html). The answer is not the final two terms though as seen [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2B2i%28-qpolygamma%28i+pi%2F2%2Ce%29+%2Bqpolygamma%28-i+pi%2F2%2Ce%29%29). [Source](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+sech%28x%29+from+0+to+infinity) for partial sum formula. Integral representation of sech [source](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sech/07/01/01/0001/). Second [source](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+t%5E%282x+i%2Fpi%29+from+x%3D0+to+b) for integral representation partial sum.

$$\mathrm{S_{sh}\mathop=^{def}\sum_{x\in\Bbb Z}sech(x)= \sum_{x\in\Bbb Z} \frac{2cosh(x)}{cosh(2x)+1}=1+2\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{e^x+e^{-x}}=1+2i\lim_{n\to\infty} ψ_e\left(n-\frac{i\pi}2+1\right)-ψ_e\left(n-\frac{i\pi}2+1\right)-ψ_e\left(\frac{i\pi}2\right)+ ψ_e\left(-\frac{i\pi}2\right)}$$

Integral representation:

$$\mathrm{S_{sh}=\sum_{x\in\Bbb Z}\frac2\pi\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{\frac{2x i}{\pi}}}{t^2+1}dt=1+\frac1\pi\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_0^\infty\frac{1}{t^2+1}\sum_{x=0}^bt^\frac{2xi}\pi dt= 1+\frac1\pi\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_0^\infty\frac{t^\frac{2i(b+1)}{\pi}-1}{\left(t^\frac{2i}{\pi}-1\right)(t^2+1)}dt=3.14224265993564633914314598537…>\pi=3.1415..}$$

[Jacobi theta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) about page. [Alternate forms](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta3/03/01/02/). After a change of functions, @Gary found that the constant has the closed form of:

$$\mathrm{S_{sh}=\vartheta_3^2\left(\frac1e\right)}$$

Also from @Gary. As a bonus, this hyperbolic cosecant version has other forms, but this is the simplest closed form. The q-digamma term is about $\pi$:

$$\mathrm{\sum_{x\ge1}csch(x)=-ln\left(e^2-1\right)-ψ_{e^2}\left(\frac12\right)= 1.284423027303676524572857579841…}$$

Another interesting thing is the integral expression. How do I evaluate S in closed form as it most likely can be expressed in terms of the q-digamma function above? Also, how would one even derive the sum using the q digamma function? Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: Maybe there are forms in terms of simpler functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we expand
$$
\operatorname{sech}n = e^{ - n} \frac{1}{{1 + e^{ - 2n} }} = e^{ - n} (1 - e^{ - 2n}  + e^{ - 4n}  -  \cdots )
$$
and change the order of summation, we obtain
$$
S=1 + 4\sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^m }}{{e^{2m + 1}  - 1}}}  = \vartheta _3^2 (0,e^{ - 1} ),
$$
where
$$
\vartheta _3 (z,q) = \sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^{ \infty } {q^{n^2 } e^{2niz} } 
$$
is a Jacobi theta function. An alternative series is
$$
S=\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {r_2 (n)e^{ - n} } ,
$$
where $r_2(n)$ is the number of representations of $n$ by the sum of two squares, allowing zeros and distinguishing signs and order.

Comment: This is a great answer with a closed form. Is it possible to simplify the answer down even more? I know it is simple already.[Proof of decimal expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=theta%283%2C0%2C1%2Fe%29%5E2)

Comment: From the theta representation we also have $$
\sqrt S  = 1 + 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {e^{ - n^2 } } 
$$ which converges rather fast. There is no simple closed-form representation for this sum and hence for $S$.

Comment: Note that $
\sqrt S  \approx 2\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - t^2 } dt}  = \sqrt \pi  
$ which explains your observation that $S$ is close to $\pi$.

Comment: I see, I thought this was a coincidence or a convoluted similarity. There is also the version of $\sum_{x=1}^\infty \text{csch(x)}=1.28442…$, but I will save this for a later time. You have done enough and helped greatly, thanks.

Comment: I will have a look at it. Btw, your cosecant sum is $$
2\sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{e^{2m + 1}  - 1}}}  =  - \log (e^2  - 1) - \psi _{e^2 } \left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right).
$$