# Does $\mathrm{\sum\limits_{-\infty}^\infty Ai(x)=1}$? Also on $\sum\limits_{-\infty}^0 \mathrm{Bi(x)}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics, special-functions, bessel-functions, airy-functions

This question will be very similar to:

> [On $$\mathrm{\sum\limits_{x=1}^\infty Ci(x)}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4222589/on-mathrm-sum-limits-x-1-infty-cix)

and

> [On $$\mathrm{\sum_{x\in\Bbb Z}sech(x), \sum_{x=1}^\infty csch(x)}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4204071/on-mathrm-sum-x-in-bbb-zsechx-3-142242)

all of which had closed forms, but it will use this [Airy Ai function](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/AiryAi/) definition which is a type of [**Bessel function**](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/).

Note that I will actually focus on 2 constants which each converge slowly. I will use $\sum\limits_{n=a}^b A_n=\sum\limits_a^b A_n$ for shorthand and use the following notations. The reason these are split up is because one of the constants may possibly diverge. Note that $\mathrm A_{0,1}$ both have a lower bound of $0$, so the x=$0$ term will be subtracted:

$$\mathrm{A_0=\sum_{-\infty}^0 Ai(x), A_1=\sum_0^\infty Ai(x),A=A_0+A_1-Ai(0)=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty Ai(x)}$$

Here is a graph of the summand:
[image]

Here is a possible [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula) computation.

$$\mathrm{A_0=\sum_0^{\infty}Ai(-x)\mathop=^{Abel}_{Plana}\frac12 Ai(-0)+\int_0^\infty Ai(-x) \,dx+\int_0^\infty\frac{Ai(- -ix)-Ai(- ix)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}\,dx=\frac{1}{3^\frac23 2Γ\left(\frac23\right)}+\frac23+ \int_0^\infty\frac{Ai(ix)-Ai(- ix)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}\,dx}$$

$$\mathrm{A_1=\sum_0^\infty Ai(x)= \mathop=^{Abel}_{Plana}\frac12 Ai(0)+\int_0^\infty Ai(x) \,dx+\int_0^\infty\frac{Ai(-ix)-Ai( ix)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}\,dx= \frac{1}{3^\frac23 2Γ\left(\frac23\right)}+\frac13+ \int_0^\infty\frac{Ai(-ix)-Ai( ix)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}\,dx}$$

This means that the conjectured answer is:

$$\mathrm{A=\sum_{x\in\Bbb Z}Ai(x)=A_0+A_1-Ai(0) \mathop=^{Abel}_{Plana} \frac{1}{3^\frac23 2Γ\left(\frac23\right)}+\frac23+ \int_0^\infty\frac{Ai(ix)-Ai(- ix)}{e^{2\pi x}-1} \, dx + \frac{1}{3^\frac23 2Γ\left(\frac23\right)}+\frac13+ \int_0^\infty\frac{Ai(-ix)-Ai( ix)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}\,dx-Ai(0)= \frac{1}{3^\frac23 Γ\left(\frac23\right)}+ 1+\int_0^\infty\frac{Ai(ix)-Ai( -ix)+Ai(-ix)-Ai(-ix)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}\,dx-\frac{1}{3^\frac23 Γ\left(\frac23\right)}}=1 $$

My final conjecture is the following with alternate forms. Note that some simplifications are possible, but change the definition. The following also uses [Hypergeometric functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/):

$$\mathrm{1\mathop=^?A=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty Ai(x)=\sum_{x\in\Bbb Z}Ai(x)= \sum_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{\,_0F_1\left(\frac23,\frac{x^3}{9}\right)}{3^\frac23Γ\left(\frac23\right)}-\frac{\,_0F_1\left(\frac43,\frac{x^3}{9}\right)}{\sqrt[3]3 Γ\left(\frac13\right)}\right)} =\sum_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\left(x^\frac32\right)^\frac13I_{-\frac13}\left(\frac{2x^\frac32}{3}\right)-x \left(x^\frac32\right)^{-\frac13} I_\frac13\left(\frac{2x^\frac32}{3}\right)\right)  $$

**There are also variations with the [Airy Bi function](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/airy/bi.html), and the [Scorer functions Gi and Hi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorer%27s_function).** Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: Don't you get $1$ when you add up the two Abel-Plana results and subtract the extra $\operatorname{Ai}(0)$? The integrals just cancel each other out.

Comment: @Gary This formula implies that the sum over the integers is just the area under the function, so the sum is the same as the integral. Good observation. I used it in the problem. The formula does not always work.

Comment: $\operatorname{Ai}(\pm ix)$ grows [too fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function#Asymptotic_formulae) for the Abel-Plana to be applicable.

Comment: I don't even see a clearway justification that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\operatorname{Ai}(n)$ converges. According to the [asymptotics](https://dlmf.nist.gov/9.7#E9), this is equivalent to the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{1/4}}\sin\left(\frac23 n^{3/2}+\frac\pi4\right)$, which is not at all obvious. (And I don't trust your numerical experiments *not related to regularised things*.)

Comment: Just for fun, [**this is the partial sum plot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSyP3.jpg) of your sine series.

Comment: Linking to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2374620) (the convergence issue is still open).

Comment: @metamorphy Using $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n^a)}{n^b}$ converging if $b>\max(a,1-a),a>0$, the sum is $\frac1{\sqrt 2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(\frac23n^{3/2})}{n^\frac14}+\frac1{\sqrt2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(\frac23n^{3/2})}{n^\frac14}$. However, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(m n^a)}{n^b}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(m n^a)}{n^b}$’s convergence is unknown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got something in terms of a theta function:
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^\infty  \operatorname{Ai}(n) & =
\sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{1}{\pi }\Re \int_0^{ + \infty } {\exp \left( {i\left( {\tfrac{1}{3}t^3  + nt} \right)} \right)dt} } \\ &  = \frac{1}{\pi }\Re \int_0^{ + \infty } {\exp \left( {i\tfrac{1}{3}t^3 } \right)\sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^\infty  {\exp \left( {i n   t} \right)} dt} 
\\ &
 = \frac{1}{\pi }\Re \int_0^{ + \infty } {\exp \left( {i\tfrac{1}{3}t^3 } \right)\theta _3 \!\left( {\tfrac{t}{2},1} \right)dt} \\ & = \frac{1}{\pi }\int_0^{ + \infty } {\cos \left( {\tfrac{1}{3}t^3 } \right)\theta _3 \!\left( {\tfrac{t}{2},1} \right)dt} .
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks. Also, the function is technically not defined for:$\vartheta_3\left(\frac x2,1\right)$ as $\vartheta_3\left(\frac x2,z\right),|z|<1$ as seen [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta3/02/). Using z=.99, the integral evaluates to: $3.14157$, but we have a factor of $\frac1\pi$, so this means the Abel Plana formula should work and the $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} Ai(x)=1$ while the unregularized sum is $\pi$. Right?

Comment: one last thing can you help me with:$$\sum_{x=-\infty}^0 \text{Bi}(x)$$? Using the other main Airy function?

Comment: You can use http://dlmf.nist.gov/9.5.E3 to obtain an expression in terms of two integrals.

Comment: A few words on why I don't think this should be *accepted*. In the distributional sense, $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\exp(int)=2\pi\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\delta(t-2n\pi)$$ is known as [Dirac comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb), but this is *not* applicable here (the integration is outside of an application of the theory of distributions, and the resulting series doesn't converge). I wonder if this can be "fixed".

Answer (score 0):

**This will be a section for the “variations” mentioned in the question:**

Corollary for Abel-Plana formula:

Let $f(x)$ fit the conditions for the Abel-Plana, $f(ix)-f(-ix)+f(-ix)-f(ix)=0$, and $f(0)$  exist then:

$$\sum_{\Bbb Z} f(x)=-f(0)+\sum_0^{\infty} f(-x)+\sum_0^\infty f(x)=-f(0)+\frac12 f(-0)+\int_0^\infty f(-x)dx+i\int_0^\infty \frac{f(- - ix)-f(-ix)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx+\frac12 f(0)+\int_0^\infty f(x) dx+i\int\frac{f(-ix)-f(ix)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx=-f(0)+f(0)+\int_0^\infty f(-x)+f(x) dx+i \int_0^\infty \frac{f(ix)-f(-ix)+f(-ix)-f(ix)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx=\int_0^\infty f(x)+f(-x) dx= \int_{\Bbb R} f(x)dx$$

Therefore a nice, not so useless, final result is:

$$\sum_{\Bbb Z} f(x)=\int\limits_{\Bbb R} f(x) dx$$
Ai variation:

Using @Gary’s result and the [numerical integration](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+cos%28x%5E3%2F3%29theta%283%2Cx%2F2%2C.99%29+from+0+to+infinity) shows that $A=1$. Now let us define the uregularized [main integral definitions](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/AiryAi/07/01/01/) of the Airy Ai function. Note that I use $\Bbb R=[-\infty,\infty]$ and the derived corollary:

$$\sum_{x\in\Bbb Z} \int_0^\infty \cos\left(\frac{t^3}{3}+tx\right)dt= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_0^\infty \cos\left(\frac{t^3}{3}+tx\right)dt\,dx=\pi, \sum_{x\in\Bbb Z} \int_{\Bbb R} e^{i\left(\frac{t^3}{3}+tx\right)}dt= \iint_\limits{\Bbb R^2} e^{i\left(\frac{t^3}{3}+tx\right)}dt\,dx=2\pi$$

Bi version using @Gary’s suggestion of [DLMF 9.5.3](http://dlmf.nist.gov/9.5.E3) and my finding of the [Scorer function integral representations](https://dlmf.nist.gov/9.12)

$$\pi\sum_{-\infty}^0\text{Bi}(x)= \sum_{x=0}^\infty  \int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{t^3}{3}-tx}dt+ \sum_{x=0}^\infty \int_0^\infty \sin\left(\frac{t^3}{3}+tx\right)dt= \pi \sum_{x=0}^\infty (\text{Gi}(x)+\text{Hi}(-x))$$